# python pickle, not storing list elements on reload

Tags: python, list, pickle

I am very new to coding and for this specific code, I'm lost.
the purpose of the program is to make a list of user input of names, store it, and reload when the program restarts.
The program does not throw an error but it also does not store anything on the reload.
my question is, why is the list not saved?
any help would be appreciated.

here is the code I tried:

### python 2.7

```
    <pre>
import os
import pickle

def display_title_bar():
    os.system('cls')
    print("\t***  Greeter - Hello old and new friends!  ***")

#user choice
def get_user_choice():
    print('1- list peopel we know: ')
    print('2- add someone new: ')
    print('3- enter q to exit')
    return raw_input('please enter 1 2 or q :')
    
    
def show_name():
    print(' here are the people we know\n')
    for name in names:
        print(name.title())
        
def get_new_name():
    new_name=raw_input(' please enter name: ')
    if new_name in names:
        print(' we allready know %s' %new_name)# test for existing members.
    else:
        names.append(new_name)
        print('%s has been added to the list\n'%new_name)
def load_names():
    try:
        file_object=open('names.pydata','rb')
        pickle.dump( names, file_object)
        file_object.close()
        return names
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return[]
def quit():
    try:
        file_object =open('names.pydata','wb')
        pickle.dump(names,file_object)
        file_object.close()
        print(' i will rmemeber the names')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(' sorry something went wrong')
        
#Setup a loop where users can choose 
names= load_names()
choice=''
display_title_bar()

while choice !='q':
    # Respond to the user's choice.
    choice=get_user_choice()
    display_title_bar()
    if choice=='1':
        show_name()
    elif choice =='2':
        get_new_name()
        
    elif choice =='q': 
        quit()
        print('thanks see you again soon')
    else:
        print(' i dont know what is this\n')
                                          
   <code>
```

Comment: You're doing the same thing to convert a Python object to a pickled representation as you are to convert a pickled representation into a Python object. It can't be correct in both places.

Comment: Thank you, I have replaced the load_name with pickle.load and worked through it, thank you